# Suggestions of a good video on intermediate Mountain Biking skills: getting up (and down)  1' obstacles 

Tags: mountain-bike, training

I'm looking for a good training video on intermediate mountain biking skills.
(I've been mt biking for about 12 years and I'd like to improve my skills.)

I'm looking for a video that really breaks the skills down and maybe provides suggestions of drills to practice.

I'm looking for DVDs or online videos (YouTube, etc.).

*Update:*

Skills I'm looking for:

- Getting over 5" to 12" tall obstacles (rocks, fallen trees).
- Manual Wheel lift (which would probably help with the above).
- Jumping /Descending down something really steep (2' drop off, etc.)

Comment: What's "intermediate" to you?

Comment: What kind of skills for what kind of riding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't included on your list, but the motion used for bunny hopping applies. I watched the following a while ago and thought it was informative:

For 'getting up', you can combine a manual and bunny hop. What I normally do when approaching an obstacle that I want to hop over, is shift my weight back, then pull up on my wheel (just before reaching the obstacle). Getting your front wheel up is accomplished by pulling back evenly with both arms while making a hard pedal-stroke (you'll need to be in a small enough gear). Right before your wheel(s) come in contact with the obstacle, 'un-weight' your rear wheel and gently push your bars forward. Even if your wheels don't leave the ground, once you learn to un-weight your rear wheel, you'll naturally ramp off the obstacle, even if it's square like a curb. With practice you'll eventually start hopping before you contact the object.

If you have trouble putting it all together, try not to get frustrated. It can take a while to develop the co-ordination and strength required to complete each motion. I find that one of the best ways to ease your learning experience is to ride your local trails with riders that are a bit better than you. Watch what they do and try to follow their lines when you're comfortable. Pay particular attention to 'how' they ride certain obstacles/corners/descents.

Comment: +1 for riding with people better than yourself. ALWAYS the best way to learn, especially if you are competitive.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Dana's answer: If you don't know anyone who can show you the moves (always the best way to learn), then get onto Youtube and search for "MTB bunny hop training" and "MTB drop off training".  You should find thousands of videos of people showing you what to do.

Comment: The trick is finding *good* videos :-)